# A topological space extracting from a group action

Tags: gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, group-actions

Let  $G$ be  a  compact  abelian topological  group with invariant measure $\mu$ which  acts  on  a  compact  Hausdorff  space  $X$. A  $G$-odd function is  a  continuous  function $f:X\to  \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_{G} f(gx)d\mu =0\;\;\forall x\in X$. Let $A$ be  the non unital $C^{*}$ subalgebra  of  $C(X)$  generated  by  odd  functions.

$A$ is  a (non unital) $C^{*}$ algebra, so it is  isomorphic to $C_{0}(Y)$, for some  locally  compact  hausdorff space $Y$.

What  can  be  said  about $A$  and  $Y$.

> Is  $A$ an  Ideal in $C(X)$? Is  $Y$ embeddable  in $X$?Is  $Y$  homeomorphic to $(X-\text{fixed points of  $G$})$?

Note that  for the obvious  action of  $Z_{2}$  on the  interval $[-1,\;1]$ the answers to  above questions  are affirmative. In fact $A=\{f\in C[-1,\;1]\mid f(0)=0\}$. So $Y=[-1,\;1]-\{0\}$.

Now assume that  we  have  a non commutative  dynamical  system(G  acts  on  a noncommutative  $C^{*}$  algebra).  What  is an  appropriate  NC  space  $Y$, as  a non commutativization of the  above  process?

Comment: Is not in your example $Y=(0,1]$? Because $f(-x)=-f(x)$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  No the  algebra  $A$ is the  non unital $C^{*}$  **algebra generated** by odd function. So it is equal to the  algebra  of  all continuous  functions  $f$  with f(0)=0.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  So  it is  the  ideal of  continuoes  function with  compact supoert in $[-1,\;1]-\{0\}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  thank you very much for  your comment on consideration of  action of  G  on itself. As you said, for  G finite the  space  $Y=X-\emptyset=X$. Now I try to  concentrate on infinite  group. What  do  you think  about $G=S^{1}$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  I think for $G=X=S^{1}$, the algebra $A$ is again the  whole algebra  because $f(z)=z$ and $f(z)=\bar{z}$ are $G$-odd functions. Now  what  about $S^{3}$  which is  acted  by itself  or $S^{1}$?

Comment: and more generally, $S^{2n+1}$ which is  acted  by $S^{1}$.